# copy the functionality of a js function to angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a `javascript` function like this:

```
  function undo() {

    if (index <= 0) {
        index = 0;
        canvas.loadFromJSON(state[index]);
        canvas.renderAll();
        return;
    }

    index--;
    console.log('undo');
    canvas.loadFromJSON(state[index]);
    canvas.renderAll();
    action = false;
}
```

I want to declare the same function in Angularjs. Will it work the same way in angular also? And if not what are the changes I have to make?

Answer (score 0):

The controller part of `Angularjs` is essentially javascript. It will work perfectly. You have to make sure the function's context remains same.

Comment: @mo8 thanks for your response...do you have any demo of that...that will be a good help